# How can i add the first index number to n index times in array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, primeng

I have a variables with the specific values,

```
    var total = 20;
    var arr = [5];
```

and i want to divide this variable to get a times of division count,so i added the code to get remainder,

```
   var inc = Math.ceil(total / arr[0]);
```

Now If inc value is 4 ,I want to display the variable **arr** to **[5,10,15,20]**.We have arr[0] is 5 and total is 20, in between two indexes i want to loop.

So, I written a code to get above format,

```
    for (let i = 1 ; i<=inc - 2; i++) {
            arr[i] = 5;
            arr[i+1] = total
      }
       console.log(arr) => [ 5, 5, 5, 20 ] I AM GETTING THIS VALUE.
```

Please help me on these issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what will be the output if arr was `[6]` ??

Comment: so where do you increase total?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Array.from` with a callback were you do `step * counter + step` to count upwards

```js
var total = 20;
var step  =  5;
var steps = total / step;

const arr = Array.from({ length: steps }, (_, i) => (step * i + step));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code add 5 multiple times

I changed the `for` loop :

```
var total = 20;
var arr = [5];
var inc = Math.ceil(total / arr[0]);

for (let i = 1; i < inc; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i-1] + 5;
}
console.log(arr);
```